# Row wise comparison of a string column in R data frame to create a new column

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning

I have to perform a row-wise comparison on a string column of a data frame and then compare it to a second data frame. The test data frame is showcased below -

```
pat_id  line_code month_rule
1        r        0
1        chop     0
1        rchop    0
1        rchop    0
1        rchp     0
1        rchp     0
1        rchop    1
1        fr       0
2        f        0
2        fr       0
2        fr       1
```

The bench data frame(benchmark) has the standard line codes for comparison. Below is the sample benchmark data frame -

```
line_code
gb
rc
br
fr
ir
r2
rchop
rcyclo
rcvp
rfnd
rcp
cp
```

The focus is to create a new column in test data frame which identifies if it is a new line. Below are the conditions to identify the new line -

1. If the month_rule is 1, it is a new line
2. For patient 1, till row 6 it all belongs to a single line. This is because, the strings "r", "chop","rchp" are not part of the benchmark data frame.
3. In row 7, patient 1 has "fr" line code which matches with benchmark data frame and hence it is a new line as well.

The final output data will look similar to this -

```
pat_id  line_code month_rule line
1        r        0          1
1        chop     0          1
1        rchop    0          1
1        rchop    0          1
1        rchp     0          1
1        rchp     0          1
1        rchop    1          2
1        fr       0          3
2        f        0          1
2        fr       0          1
2        fr       1          2
```

My approach was to solve this using dplyr. Since there were so many conditions, I wasn't able to get to the final solution. Here is how I was thinking about it -

```
library(dplyr)
test<-test%>%rowwise()%>%
      mutate(test$line=ifelse(month_rule==0 & test$line_code!=bench$line_code), 1,0)
```

This is not the final solution. But, is there a better way to solve it?

Comment: `rchop` is in benchmark data frame, why doesn't it bring a new line in `pat_id == 1` at line 3; And `fr` is also in benchmark data frame, and it doesn't bring a new line for `pat_id == 2` at line 10?

Comment: Please share data via `dput()` when using the `r` tag. Hover your mouse over the tag for more info.

Comment: @Psidom Basically, line codes are the different medications provided to a patient during a time frame. For patient==1 in row 1, he is only given "r" medication. In row 2 he is given "c","h","o","p" medication. In line 3 he is given all the "rchop" medication but  is still part of line 1. In row 6, only "rchp" is given but it still belongs to line 1 for that patient.

Comment: What is the purpose of benchmark data frame then? `rchop` and `fr` are both in the benchmark data frame, but you ignore them conditionally which doesn't seem like a consistent logic to me.

Comment: @Psidom A new line occurs only if the month_rule==1 and test$line_code==bench$line_code. In all other cases, it either belongs to a preceding or a succeeding line number.

Comment: *A new line occurs only if the month_rule==1 and test$line_code==bench$line_code*. At row 7, `month_rule != 1` and `line_code %in% bench$line_code`, which means it should not be a new line? But it is according to your output and condition statement.

Comment: @Psidom For patient==1, till row 6, all the medications are provided within two months(month_rule==0) and all the medications revolve around "rchop" hence it is all line 1. But in row 7, even though the patient is given "rchop" again but this time it has exceeded the two-month time frame(month_rule==1) hence this becomes a new line.

Comment: OK. I am sorry. When I say row 7, I mean row 8. I mis counted.

Comment: @Psidom No worries. For patient==1, in row 8, he is totally given a new medication called "fr" which is part of benchmark and hence this qualifies for a new line. So the line count becomes 3. Let me put it this way, there are  two conditions to get a new line - Condition 1 - If month_rule==1; Condition 2 - New medication from benchmark data even though the difference between last(row 7) and recent (row 8) medication is less than two months.

Comment: Well. Then it is a little bit complicated. For instance, if you have another `r` after `fr`, does it count as a new medication? Maybe since `r` belongs to a lot of other line_codes and maybe not, `r` belongs to `fr` as well.

Comment: Just to provide a little bit useful information, aside from the other conditions, for instance if you want to create new line based on the month_rule, you can use cumsum as `test %>% group_by(pat_id) %>% mutate(line = cumsum(month_rule))` from where you might figure out how to incorporate other conditions.

Comment: @Psidom For patient==1 if there is "r"(row 9) after "fr"(row 8) and the month_rule==0. Then the new line count would still be 3 since we haven't encountered a medication which matches with a benchmark medication. Let`s assume for the same patient if there is "rchop"(row 10) and month_rule==0, then line count becomes 4.

Comment: I dont' get what happens at line 3, for patient 1: he's given a new medication from benchmark data, so why doesn't he get a new line? Same thing at line 10 for patient 2.

Comment: @Scarabee Because, the month_rule==0(given within two months) and in row 3 "rchop" is just the combination of "r" and "chop" given in row 1 and 2 respectively.

Comment: Yes that explanation works for row 3, but what about row 10? "fr" is not a combination of "f".

Comment: @Scarabee in row 10, "fr" is a combination of "f". It basically means, patient==2 medication was started with "f" and during the next visit, he is given "fr" which matches with a benchmark. If not, the same patient may be started with "r" in row 10 and given "fr" in row 11 which still follows the similar pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
test <- test %>% 
  group_by(pat_id) %>% 
  mutate(var1 = (line_code %in% bench$line_code)) %>%
  mutate(var2 = ifelse(row_number() > 1, 
                       mapply(grepl, lag(line_code), line_code),
                       0)) %>%
  mutate(line = 1 + cumsum(month_rule | (var1 & !var2))) %>%
  select(-var1, -var2)
```

`var1` is true if and only if `line_code` is part of the benchmark data frame.

`var2` is true if and only if `line_code` is a "combination" (as you say) of the very previous `line_code`. (I'm not sure that's exactly what you want, please test it on your real dataset)

So `month_rule | (var1 & !var2)` is true if and only if the month rule is satisfied OR (the medication is from benchmark data AND new). Therefore `line` is your expected result.